# Show elements that have a data attr object with the checked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

Above is a list of checkboxes, simple start right. Two of them are checked. I then below have a list of panels that I would like to be hidden or shown depending if the panels data attr array called data-category contains HR or Customer Service.

an example of the data array:

```
["Legal and Regulatory","Marketing","HR","Cusomer Service"]
```

The problem:

The JS below from my inspection seems to be showing elements that was the last checked checkbox. For example if I clicked "HR" last then this would show the panels for "HR" and not for "Customer Service" too.

So what I would like is to show the panels that data attr include "Customer Service" and "HR". However if a data attr didn't have for example "Sales" but does have "Customer Service" and "HR" and "Sales" became checked. It would then be hidden.

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $('.pagination, .callout').hide();

  $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    var checkboxName = $(this).val();

    $('.callout').hide().each(function() {
      var calloutArray = $(this).data();

      if (calloutArray.category.indexOf(checkboxName) !== -1) {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });

  var countChecked = $('.checkbox').filter(':checked').length;

  if (countChecked === 0) {
    $('.callout').show();
    $('.pagination').show();

    pagination();
  }

});
```

To summarise that, basically if the data attr goes not contain the checked input then hide otherwise if all checked boxes do exist show the panel.

I hope I've explained this. Please leave comments for further information needed.

**** EDIT *****

Checkbox HTML:

```
<ul class="category-filters">
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="Customer Service" type="checkbox">Customer Service</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="Finance" type="checkbox">Finance</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="HR" type="checkbox">HR</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="Legal and Regulatory" type="checkbox">Legal and Regulatory</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="Marketing" type="checkbox">Marketing</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="Operations" type="checkbox">Operations</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="Risk Management" type="checkbox">Risk Management</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="Sales" type="checkbox">Sales</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input class="checkbox" value="Technology" type="checkbox">Technology</label>
    </li>           
</ul>
```

And these are the panels:

```
<div style="display: none;" class="callout horizontal word-wrap" data-category="[&quot;Customer Service&quot;,&quot;HR&quot;,&quot;Operations&quot;,&quot;Risk Management&quot;,&quot;Technology&quot;]">

    <img src="http://localhost/vallum/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/David-King.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="David-King" srcset="http://localhost/vallum/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/David-King.jpg 480w, http://localhost/vallum/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/David-King-277x300.jpg 277w" sizes="(max-width: 639px) 98vw, (max-width: 1199px) 64vw, 480px">
    <h5>David King</h5>
    <p>With over 19 year’s experience of working</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide html markup and possible then please create plunker or fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice will amend

Comment: Your `data-category` attributes have HTML-escaped double-quotes? bleh...

Comment: Its generated by PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looping the checkboxes and hiding all the panels on each checkbox iteration, this undoes the work of the previous checkbox iteration.

```
$('.callout').hide().each(function() {
```

is your problem. You are already hiding all the panels before you loop the checkboxes so just remove the hide:

```
$('.callout').each(function() {
```